# Distinct count needed within case when statement

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a query of all people who were screened for smoking status and need a count of unique patients. I am pulling from an encounter table, so the patient could have been asked multiple times. In my case when statement I would like to limit the "Then..." result to something like "Then count distinct patients" but it is giving me an error about aggregates not being allowed within an aggregate. If I remove it, it will then not produce a total as I wish and it's telling me I need it in the group by clause, which I do not want. limit is not an option in sql-server to the best of my knowledge

```
,count(case when soc.tobacco_user_c in (1, 2, 4, 5) and dmw.SMOKING_CESS_CNSL_YN ='y' then enc.PAT_ID **Here is where I want a unique count of patients** end) Compliant
```

Comment: You can make it a correlated query, case when COND then (SELECT..) else (SELECT..)

Comment: returns... Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery if I change it to ,count (case when soc.tobacco_user_c in (1, 2, 4, 5) and dmw.SMOKING_CESS_CNSL_YN ='y' then (select distinct enc.PAT_ID) else 0 end) Compliant

Comment: do i meant case when soc.tobacco_user_c in (1, 2, 4, 5) and dmw.SMOKING_CESS_CNSL_YN ='y' then (select count(distinct enc.PAT_ID) from YourTable) else 0 end or something like that.. without the count, count it inside the subquery

Comment: I tried that, too and then it tells me I need in the group by clause of my overall query rather than just giving that count value as a result

Comment: Can you please add a table structure with a couple of lines.  It seems likeit would be simpler to first select all of the encounters of screening people, filtered by dates or whatever filter you want.  And then counting the unique identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [DISTINCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132161.aspx) with a [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx) expression.

**Example**

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tobacco = 1 THEN PAT_ID ELSE NULL END)
...
;
```

I've abbreviated your example to make it easier to read.  NULLs will not be included in the final count, so there is no need to worry about [off by one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) errors.

Comment: I used distinct case, but because there are multiple encounters each is considered a distinct case and the pat-id is counted for each instead of 1 pat_id regardless of the number of encounters

Comment: DISTINCT will only count the number of unique Pat-Ids.  Is a Pat-Id unique to a patient or an encounter?  If you could add sample data and expected output to your question I can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Pat_enc_ID Pat_ID Smoking
1234          1111           2
5678          1111               3

Comment: That looked better when I was typing then when I hit enter. There are two pat_enc_ids for same patient, each with a smoking status. It is counting those as 2 instead of 1

Comment: I'm sorry this doesn't really help.  Your sample includes the tables soc and dmw.  Can you edit your question to include 4 or 5 sample rows for each table.  Then add an expected output.  Remember to include all relevant and joining columns.  If you can show us manually what is required we can help with the coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
case when soc.tobacco_user_c in (1, 2, 4, 5) and dmw.SMOKING_CESS_CNSL_YN ='y' then COUNT(DISTINCT enc.PAT_ID) ELSE 0 end Compliant
```

Comment: how can I do this with then not having to put the dmw column in my group by clause

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating two subqueries and then doing a select count distinct on each of the max columns in those queries to limit the results to one